# why phantomjs throws phantomjs://code/bootstrap.js:435

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

i don't have any clue about this `error` code `phantomjs://code/bootstrap.js:435`

What is the reason behind it And how can i fix it.

i have installed `phantomjs` globally and have pasted all the `code` in a file called `twitter.js`   from this link     http://code-epicenter.com/how-to-login-to-twitter-using-casperjs-and-phantomjs-and-extract-tweets/

i'm running it through `php` like this

> files are in the same folder

**index.php**

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0);

$response = exec('phantomjs twitter.js');

echo  $response
```

please help me thanks in advance!

Comment: Error: context and details missing on line 1.

Comment: Or in other words: we neither have any clue about this error you're talking about. Maybe we could help you if you provided details.

Comment: Please provide a code sample, preferably with the target site's url.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak,i have included the example code with the link

Comment: @Vaviloff,i have included the example code with the link

Comment: To get full response of `exec` you need to run it like `exec('phantomjs twitter.js', $response);` Otherwise you just get the last line, Please, correct your script and provide the full error log. Also: why don't you debug it without PHP first?

Comment: @Vaviloff, thanks for `correcting` me i will do that and come back